# Is Qualcomm safe to keep on phone or is it a security threat?

Tags: settings, downloading, system-apps

I have a lot of stuff downloaded on my phone like `com.qualcomm.qti.simsettings`, all starting with Qualcomm.

Should these be on my phone? What little I did read it said security threat. Should I delete all these?

Comment: if these apps were downloaded instead of being installed by the OEM then this is a real security threat and you shoulf remove them

Answer (score 2):

Yes. They are completely safe to have.

In fact, they are helper programs for [Qualcomm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualcomm) parts, for example the SoC, the modem, or another chip in the phone.

**Do not** try to remove or disable them - your phone will sooner or later run into random issues.